# SharePoint 2010 Versions MIssing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I had a workflows that created 3000+ versions inside a list. I modified the workflow to fix this issue. This made the list size very large. I went in and changed the version limit down to 25. I then started to delete the version history to reduce the overall size of the list. Some of the list items only have 25 items and not 3000 different versions. I have deleted all the version history and the list is still very large. Did some of the version history get hidden? There are no attachments in the list. Is there a bulk way to delete all the version history? Is there a way to verify that the versions are hidden? Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "the list is still very large"? Number of list items? Number of item versions? Size of database file?

Comment: The overall list is 500 MB. I think it should only be a couple MB

Answer (score 0):

Item versions are not trimmed down to the new setting of 25 until the item is checked in at least once. This trimming takes effect then. If you need to shrink the list immediately, you will need to use a script to check out and check in each item which will ensure all of them are shrunk to only having 25 items.

Comment: I have gone through all the items in the list and looked at the version history. If there are only 25 items then should I assume the 3000 other versions no longer exist? Is there anything else I should check that might be causing the list to be so large?